# Sounds on my MacBook Pro I can't identify-

Tags: macos, audio, games

There is a sound constantly playing on my MacBook Pro laptop.  When I connect to the internet, this sound which seems to be a bouncing ball with a spring is always playing in the background.  I can be listening to a song, a lecture, or nothing.
I have turned the sound off on any games I play because I thought the sound was coming from a game.  I have closed out every open window.  I have checked my settings.  I have turned the computer off and when I turn it on, the sound is still there.  I don't know how to stop the sound.  Thank you for any suggestions you might have to help me get rid of this sound.

Comment: Just to be clear - if you log in and there's no internet connection you have no sounds playing. Only when the network has a working route to the internet does the sound start and continue until you disconnect?

Comment: I had similar issue once, caused by QuickLook Satellite. Basically it was "previewing" some youtube page from bookmarks... And it launched that preview because of Spotlight. Your case will be different though, if it's some "bouncing ball" sound. Close all apps, launch Activity Monitor and look for any leftover app which should not be running.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much for your help.  I am enjoying the quiet (and so is my husband!)